# What is "The Tale of Despereaux" referring to that is illegal?

Tags: tale-of-despereaux

There is one line where they are talking about making something illegal that is a natural part of the world. Are they talking about the soup, rats or something else?

Quote, 
"What happens when you make something illegal that is a natural part of the world?"

It's about 15 minutes into the film.

Comment: Can you quote the line more specifically? Are you talking about the film or the book it is based on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Both rats *and* soup are outlawed

From the [script](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=tale-of-despereaux-the) of *The Tale of Despereaux*:

> When something hurts this much, there must be a reason.
> There must be someone to blame.

## The narrator is saying that outlawing rats and soup is as silly as trying to outlaw any other natural thing.

> What happens when you make something illegal that is just a natural part of the world? You may as well make flies illegal, or sweat, or Monday morning.
> But that's what the King did out of a terrible sadness.